# Windows 10 Mobile : Autocorrect option

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, autocorrect

I have been facing lots of problems after updating to Windows 10 Mobile Technical Preview! While texting the autocorrect option is the worst part and I want to disable it.

Can anyone help me on how to disable autocorrect in Windows 10 Mobile Tech Preview?

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings > Time & Language > Keyboard and tap on your keyboard in the list of keyboards. There you will find all autocorrect options. I believe "Correct misspelled words" is the setting you want to turn off.

Comment: Shawn thnk you very much ... :) ur solution worked

Comment: Good to hear! Please consider marking this as the answer if it helped.

Comment: This is not working for me please help